# Need to merge two ffmpeg commands

Tags: ffmpeg, java, android

I didn't understand how to concat these two commands:

```
Object split = ("-i "+filePath+" -framerate 30000/1001 -i "+Final.theme+" -filter_complex [1:v]fade=out:st=30:d=1:alpha=1[ov];[0:v][ov]overlay=10:10[v] -map [v] -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -shortest "+j).split(" ");
Object split = ("-i "+filePath+" -i "+gifpath+" -filter_complex [1]format=rgba,colorchannelmixer=aa=0.5[front];[0][front]overlay=x=10:y=10,format=yuv420p "+j).split(" ");
```

Comment: Both commands feature overlays. What is the combination of overlays that you want?

Comment: First command overlays Image and Second Command overlays GIF. And Both are at a same position-10:10

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Object split = ("-i "+filePath+" -framerate 30000/1001 -i "+Final.theme+" -i "+gifpath+" -filter_complex [1:v]fade=out:st=30:d=1:alpha=1[ov];[2]format=rgba,colorchannelmixer=aa=0.5[front];[0:v][ov]overlay=10:10[v];[v][front]overlay=x=10:y=10,format=yuv420p[v] -map [v] -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -shortest "+j).split(" ");
```